# SonarCloud check status not available in Github

Tags: github, circleci, sonarcloud

Currently, I'm using SonarCloud to analyze some of the repositories in my project. But in some of them, the check status is not present (**I want to make this mandatory**).

[image: Desired state in-branch protection]

The **CI/CD** server is CircleCI and SonarCloud it is working ok (PR branch is available).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to activate Github webhook, you must check that

1. The project in sonar has the icon of GitHub (relationship it's ok)
   [image]
2. You have to create another branch and make a **Pull Request**
3. Call the Gradle task with PR params
   `./gradlew -Dsonar.pullrequest.branch=${CIRCLE_BRANCH} -Dsonar.pullrequest.base=master -Dsonar.pullrequest.key=${CIRCLE_PULL_REQUEST##*/}`
4. Make sure that any of your repos don't override project keys